# C++ API Speech Google

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, распознавание-речи, google-speech-recognition

Всем добрый день, у меня есть вопрос, мне нужно на плюсах записать аудио в консольном приложении, отослать в google для распознавания и получить ответ, в виде текста string желательно.
Пишу в Visual Studio 2017.

Подскажите пожалуйста как это осуществить ?